# Searching for repeated elements within a C# list

Tags: c#

I need to iterate over a list and count all the elements with the same id given this model:

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to check for all the repeated elements in the list and store the count in a variable:

```
List<Product> productList = new()
            {
                new Product { ProductName = "item1", ProductId = 1},
                new Product { ProductName = "item2", ProductId = 1},
                new Product { ProductName = "item3", ProductId = 2},
                new Product { ProductName = "item4", ProductId = 2},
                new Product { ProductName = "item5", ProductId = 3},
                new Product { ProductName = "item6", ProductId = 1}
            };
```

Given the example above, the result should look like this:

```
int someProduct1 = 3;
int someProduct2 = 2;
int someProduct3 = 1;
```

How can I achieve something like that?

Comment: Answer is [here](https://www.techiedelight.com/find-duplicates-in-list-csharp/).  It was the first match in a Google search for "Find duplicates in a list c#"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    var query = productList
       .GroupBy(c => c.ProductId)
       .Select(o => new 
       {
           ProductId = o.Key,
           Count = o.Count()
       });
```

or just repeatings

```
var query = productList
       .GroupBy(c => c.ProductId)
       .Select(o => new 
       {
           ProductId = o.Key,
           Count = o.Count()
       })
       .OrderByDescending (o => o.Count )
       .Where(p => p.Count>1);
```

output

```
productId Count
    1      3
    2      2
```